# The downloadablePlot Shiny Module breaks down my shiny app upon launching

Tags: r, shiny, periscope, downloadableplot

I have the `shiny` app below and I would like to know how I can download a plot using the `downloadablePlot` Shiny Module. When I launch the app the whole app breaks down.

```
library(shiny)
library(periscope)
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot"),
  downloadablePlotUI("object_id1", 
                     downloadtypes = c("png", "csv"), 
                     download_hovertext = "Download the plot and data here!",
                     height = "500px", 
                     btn_halign = "left")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot<-renderPlot(plot(iris))
  plotInput = function() {
    plot(iris)
  }
  callModule(downloadablePlot,
             "object_id1", 
             logger = ss_userAction.Log,
             filenameroot = "mydownload1",
             aspectratio = 1.33,
             downloadfxns = list(png = plotInput()),
             visibleplot = plotInput())
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the brackets after `plotInput` when passing it as an argument

```
library(shiny)
library(periscope)
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot"),
  downloadablePlotUI("object_id1",
                     downloadtypes = c("png", "csv"),
                     download_hovertext = "Download the plot and data here!",
                     height = "500px",
                     btn_halign = "left")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot<-renderPlot(plot(iris))
  plotInput = function() {
    plot(iris)
  }
  callModule(downloadablePlot,
             "object_id1",
             logger = ss_userAction.Log,
             filenameroot = "mydownload1",
             aspectratio = 1.33,
             downloadfxns = list(png = plotInput),
             visibleplot = plotInput)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In shiny, when passing functions / reactives around, you usually need to avoid appending them with `()` as doing so evaluates them. In the above example, you were returning the **output** of plotInput instead of the function itself

Comment: You answer solves the break down issue and I will accept it for here.